# Custom Field is getting the value of another page/post instead of the current one?

Tags: custom-field

I'm using this same come in two files: `single.php` and `home.php`:

(Outside of the loop).

(There is a `#mainbar` div in both **single posts** and **home page** but the image should be different)

```
<?php // Set and display custom field
        $mainbar_right_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Right Title', true);
        $mainbar_right_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Right Image', true); ?>
        <div class="float-right">
            <h2><?php echo $mainbar_right_title; ?></h2>
            <img src="<?php echo $mainbar_right_image ?>" alt="" />
        </div> <?php
    ?>
    </div>
```

I thought the **home page** would get the value of its own custom field but instead is getting the value of the **single post**. Is this a default behaviour or I'm doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** I tried adding a value to another single post and the image is indeed the one of the post not of the another so the problem is only the home page.

home.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Home
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Prominent
 * @since Prominent 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php // Insert image using custom field
        $postimageurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Intro Image', true); ?>
        <div class="block-1">
            <img src="<?php echo $postimageurl; ?>" alt="Post Pic" />
        </div> <?php
    ?>

    <?php // Start the Loop
        if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>  <div class="block-2 padding-top">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php // Create and run custom loop
        $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
        $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Mainbar');
        while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    ?>  <div class="block-2 border-top">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // Set and display custom field
            $mainbar_left_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Left Title', true);
            $mainbar_left_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Left Image', true); ?>
            <div class="float-left">
                <h2><?php echo $mainbar_left_title; ?></h2>
                <img src="<?php echo $mainbar_left_image ?>" alt="" />
            </div> <?php
        ?>

        <?php // Set and display custom field
            $mainbar_right_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Right Title', true);
            $mainbar_right_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mainbar Right Image', true); ?>
            <div class="float-right">
                <h2><?php echo $mainbar_right_title; ?></h2>
                <img src="<?php echo $mainbar_right_image ?>" alt="" />
            </div> <?php
        ?>
        </div>

    <?php // Create and run custom loop
        $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
        $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Sidebar');
        while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    ?>  <div class="block-3 border-top">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Other_Work", true); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php // Create and run custom loop
        $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
        $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Featured');
        while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    ?>  <div class="block-2 border-top block-height-2">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php // Create and run custom loop
        $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
        $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Content');
        while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    ?>  <div class="block-3 border-top block-height-2">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p><?php the_meta(); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong.

First of all, do a `var_dump(__FILE__);` to make sure you're in the template you expect.

If that doesn't clear the mist, post the entire template, for context.

Comment: yes it is the template: string(56) "/home/alex/www/wpac/wp-content/themes/prominent/home.php". Please see my *EDIT*.

Comment: Ok, now just above `$postimageurl = ...`, do a `var_dump($post);`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why.

It is getting the ID from this line above:

```
$custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Mainbar');
```

I thought Worpdress gets the IDs of the files (not the individual loops).

This fixed the problem:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Should I include that reset at the end of every custom loop?

Comment: Yep. For `query_posts()`, use `wp_reset_query()`; for `new WP_Query()` use `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: Also, files don't have IDs. They're just files. :)

Comment: @scribu Damn, I think it was a stupid question. But somethimes Wordpress 'detect' files names to make them templates, but I guess that's another story.